# Why does "echo [a-z]" print "b t"?

Tags: bash, echo, output, brackets

What the title says. In bash, when I do:

```
$ echo [a-z]
b t
```

What does `b t` mean? Is there a special meaning for the `[` `]` operators in this context?

Comment: It prints `[a-z]` in my case.

Comment: @fedorqui Really? That is strange... I am on `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release`

Comment: I am on `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Just tested it on `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release` and it gives `[a-z]`. Perhaps there is a bug then...

Comment: Also prints `[a-z]` in `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`...

Comment: The one that gives `b t` is `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[a-z]` is a pattern that will match any file(s) whose name consists of a single letter. In your case, the current directory has two files named `b` and `t`. If there are no matching files, the pattern is treated as literal text, which is why others will see `[a-z]` printed.

Comment: Ahh that explains it. Thank you very much